# Laravel: Soft Deleted Models and Type Hinting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, type-hinting

I use [Laravel Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting) and also Type Hinting.

Is it possible to show soft-deleted models to users with appropriate privileges using type hinting. Out of the box soft-deleted models can't be type hinted (laravel throws an error).

Example Code - Routes:

```
Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UsersController', [
    'parameters' => ['id' => 'user'],
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'admin.users.index',
        'create' => 'admin.users.create',
        'store' => 'admin.users.store',
        'show' => 'admin.users.show',
        'edit' => 'admin.users.edit',
        'update' => 'admin.users.update',
        'destroy' => 'admin.users.destroy'
    ]
]);
```

And in Admin\UsersController.php

```
public function show(User $user)
{        
    // Show the $user (also if soft deleted)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *type hinted*?

Comment: In my case the UsersController's `show()` method gets a user-id. When I write `public function show(User $user)` laravel tries to find the User with the given user-id. Nothing more to do in order to get the model (at least when it is not soft-deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Customizing the Resolution Logic" section in [Explicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#explicit-binding).

You'll want to do something like this in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return App\User::withTrashed()->find($value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Small typo: `witTrashed()` should be `withTrashed()`